# Need cloud file share with api and security

Tags: cloud

My client does not want to have ftp on the production box (understandable).  We generate ftp files that we want to make available to our clients, but they do not have the ability to receive.

I need the following:

- API to automatically upload the data
- Ability to have simple ftp or http access
- Ability to secure a directory / file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I upload stats using a simple C# app on a clients server using HTTPS to our web server.

```
   using System.Net;

   WebClient client = new WebClient();

   client.UploadFile("https://website/upload", "PUT", localpathtofile);
```

Our IIS server just has a non-browsable, writable, IIS folder and an SSL certificate.